Encoding cookies in Django
It seems like Django does not encode my cookies properly
I tried using:
resp = request.get_signed_cookie('age', salt='code')

However the output for number '20' would be '20:1sl4MF:RUUEG71gABt4-MeCj_lZiuklArWiCOLTKsxKfjLvlUg', meaning that the value is still visible, and the code just adds ':' and a bunch of characters. Same goes for other numbers and strings. Is it normal or am I doing something wrong?

"signed" does not mean encrypted / encoded.

Django's get_signed_cookie doesn't encrypt it, only signs it, if you want to encrypt it, you could use cryptography package and do it like this:
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

secret_key=Fernet.generate_key().decode()
cipher_suite= Fernet(secret_key)

def encrypt(value):
    value_bytes = str(value).encode()
    encrypted_value = cipher_suite.encrypt(value_bytes)
    encrypted_value_base64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(encrypted_value).decode()
    return encrypted_value_base64

encrypted_value=encrypt_value('20')
response.set_cookie('age', encrypted_value)

